# What is the purity test for Olive oil?

Tags: oil, olive-oil

At home, how should I know whether Olive oil, I purchased, is pure enough?

[What is the purity test for Olive oil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53654/what-is-the-purity-test-for-olive-oil#comment77508_53654)

> What do you mean by "pure"? Could you please explain... –  Stephie

Pure here means that the Olive oil bottle purchased from market contains only the Olive oil extracted from the fresh Olives.

Pure means - not adulterated.

Comment: a quick google search says that you need to put some oil ni the fridge; it if solidify, then it is olive oil; if it does not solidify, then it's a mix.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure"? Could you please explain...

Comment: Pure enough for what? Pasta? Exorcism? [Killing lice?](http://www.muskegonhealth.net/programs/health/documents/lice_oiltreatment.pdf)

Comment: @Max there are plenty of oils that can be blended into olive oil so that the mixture solidifies in the fridge, and it's a poor test anyway... http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24689/my-olive-oil-didnt-solidify-in-the-fridge-is-it-fake , http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=9582

Comment: @Stephie edited post. Is that clear enough now?

Answer (score 2):

Any real test for purity in olive oil is going to require a lab (or at least lab equipment and supplies). The cost of that testing is going to far exceed the price of your bottle of oil.

For home use, then:

1. Buy from someone reputable. Unfortunately, even reputable folks sometimes get conned by their suppliers. (If you have a local farmer you can buy from directly, that risk can be avoided).
2. Taste it. Unfortunately, you'll probably only be able to notice bad fakes (even experts are fooled). As a side benefit, though, you'll also get to notice poor-quality (but genuine) olive oil.

A few countries have introduced labeling for olive oil that has been tested by an approved laboratory; if yours is one of them, you could look for certified oils.